# How to store and set the Values in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a HTML like the below,

```
 <input class="btn btn-primary" id ="b1" type="button" value="Blue">
 <input class="btn btn-primary" id ="b2" type="button" value="orange">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" id ="b3" type="button" value="green">
```

**I don't want to take the value from the HTML.** Like the below,

```
$(#b1).attr('value') or

var val = document.getElementById(ele.id).value;
```

Instead, `I need the value from the JS`.

The `default Value` for each button should be `0`. When I click the button each time, `++default value`. When it reaches `3`, again it should move to `0`.

Like,

```
default value  = default Value >= 3 ? 0 : ++defaultValue
```

```
$("button").click(function () {
  buttonVal(this);
});

function buttonVal(ele) {
  var def = [];
  def = def>=3 ? 0 : ++def;
  switch(def) 
  {
  case 0:
   def = 5;
   break;
  case 1 :
   def = 4;
   break;
  default:
   def = 0;
}
}
```

But, I used `switch` case to get the `default value`.

This line `def = def>=3 ? 0 : ++def;`is executed before the switch.

So, **It didnt work**.

Can we implement in different ways other than `switch` to get the default value ?

I need to store the default value in the `JS`.

Could anyone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: You want to store each input  value differently. like for btn1 (0,1,,2,3), btn2 (0,1.2.3), btn3(0,1,2,3)?  Do you want to show this value somewhere in html? In what structure you need this btn values when you want to retrive in js?

Comment: the button value is a string and not a number? Unsure how you want to increase "orange" by 1

Comment: @epascarello, I don't need a string from the HTML, The Value in the HTML can be of anything. But, I need to set the Value only in the JS and not in the HTML.

Comment: @Davi share expected output for those three buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your button id as key to store count number

```js
const container = document.getElementById("btn-container");

const btnValue = {};

container.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  // const v = e.target.value;
  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input"){
      const v = e.target.id;
      btnValue[v] = !btnValue[v] ? 1 : btnValue[v]==3 ? 0 : btnValue[v]+1;
      // Uncommment below code to show value on button
      // e.target.value=btnValue[v];
  }

  console.log(btnValue);
});
```

```html
<div id="btn-container">
 <input class="btn btn-primary" id ="b1" type="button" value="Blue">
 <input class="btn btn-primary" id ="b2" type="button" value="orange">
 <input class="btn btn-primary" id ="b3" type="button" value="green">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I want to confirm  with you, aren't we taking the value from the  HTML "input" using  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input"){ } .?

Comment: No, it's for checking that click event is from the element whose tag name is `input`, we did this check because we have added event listener on div not on every input button, it's called `event delegation`.

Comment: @Navneeth, Thanks for your explanation, Its so useful.  After storing the `button value` for each input. How to set the `button value` for each input. ? Because, I tried using `document.getElementById(v).value = btnValue`.` It didn't work!`.  I need the integer 0 ,1 ,2, 3 to be displayed on the button text for each `click`.

Comment: Inside if at last do `e.target.value=btnValue[v]` check updated answer, just uncomment code

Comment: Thanks. As I am new to JS, I could not understand the code , btnValue[v] = !btnValue[v] ? 1 : btnValue[v]==3 ? 0 : btnValue[v]+1;.  Could you please help? Many thanks.

Comment: Check updated answer with explanation. You can add even add more button inside div, no need to change code,

Comment: Does this code, `btnValue[v] = !btnValue[v] ? 1 : btnValue[v]==3 ? 0 : btnValue[v]+1` means, Since `btnValue = {}`. `btnValue[v] = !btnValue[v] ? 1 `// Which means, If btnValue[v] does not exists chose 1.and this condition  btnValue[v]==3 ? 0  //fails because btnValue[v] is just set to 1,  so It choses the else condition and increments the btnValue[v]+1. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, we are just checking if value not present then add new entry with1 value, else if present and equals 3 then set to 0 else just increment by 1

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could you please tell why have you used `tagName.toLowerCase` can we use this for normal JS?

Comment: try removing if condition with its brackets, then click  blank space beside `green` button and see `btnValue` in console.log,   It will add div `btn-container` also in the result. which we dont want, This is event delegation . check this https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/

Answer (score 2):

Use the [button's `dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to store the value.

```
$("button").click(function () {
    let currentValue = this.dataset.value || 0;
    if (++currentValue > 3) { currentValue = 0; }
    this.dataset.value = currentValue;
    ...
});
```